# Is it possible to use Google Maps in native Windows Phone applications?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

As I know it is possible to use Google Maps tiles in Silverlight Map control. But it violates Google terms of service. I wonder if there is a legal way to use google maps in Windows Phone native applications?

Comment: You might want to create a web page with just the Google Maps on it. That way, your app doesn't really "use" Google Maps: the website does... You can then embed that web page into your application. And, why not use Bing Maps? That's like a part of WP7...

Comment: Google Maps is commercial after 25000 daily loads (*IIRC*), Bing Maps is always free on WP7. What is it that you really want to achieve by using Google Maps instead of Bing?

Comment: bing maps doesn't show houses. also i have poor coverage in Russia.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should talk with gMaps for WP7 application creator. It is his twitter [@alexeystrakh](https://twitter.com/#!/alexeystrakh)